# Arduino UART ESP01 , json parse 4with 433 MHZ receiver and transmitter

Tags: json, arduino

I am using 2 Arduino, 1 Esp01,433 MHz 1 receiver and 1 433 MHz transmitter. The transmtiter sending uint_8 "85648217". When i write below the code.I can receive the messages and i can get response from api.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define RX 0
#define TX 1
using namespace std;
unsigned char rxBuf[512];
RH_ASK rf_driver;
void setup() {
rf_driver.init();
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
{
uint8_t buf[8];
uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen))
{ 
Serial.println("https://example.com/example/example/"+(String((char*)buf))+";headers\n");
//(String((char*)buf) is number from transmitter
String message = Serial.readString();
const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 20;
DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);

// DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, message);
//if (error) {
   // Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
    //Serial.println(error.f_str());
    
   // return;
 // }
Serial.println(doc["attribute"].as<const char*>());
Serial.println(message);
}
}
}
```

When i write code like this.I can't receive message.I am receving "07413943⸮"  or "07413943⸮ " .I don't know why is this happening.Does anyone know how can i fix this?

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define RX 0
#define TX 1
using namespace std;
unsigned char rxBuf[512];
RH_ASK rf_driver;
void setup() {
rf_driver.init();
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
{
uint8_t buf[8];
uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen))
{ 
Serial.println("https://example.com/example/example/"+(String((char*)buf))+";headers\n");
//(String((char*)buf) is number from transmitter
String message = Serial.readString();
const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 20;
DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, message);
if (error) {
Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
Serial.println(error.f_str());
    
return;
 }
Serial.println(doc["attribute"].as<const char*>());
Serial.println(message);
}
}
}
```

Comment: @Juraj it didn't worked.

Comment: sorry `Serial.print(doc["attribute"].as<const char*>());`

Comment: @Juraj it didn't worked.Don't need to say sorry i am here to try everything .I can try everything. I don't really know but i think the problem is DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, message); this line.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.It seems like i need to convert string this (String((char*)buf)) but not like this.Here is how i solved.

```
uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf)
if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen))
{ 
  rf_driver.printBuffer("Got:",buf,buflen);
  String rcv;
  for (int i=0; i<buflen;i++){
    rcv+=(char)buf[i];
  }
 Serial.print("example.com/example"+rcv+";header");
 String input = Serial.readString();
 StaticJsonDocument<32> doc;

  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc,input);

 if (error) {
 Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
 Serial.println(error.f_str());
 return;
}

float attribute= doc["attribute"]; // 428.5
Serial.println(float(attribute));
Serial.println(input);
```